# ModuleNoFoundError: No module named 'stuff' exception when trying to run a Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I tried very simple python but dont know where error comes from.

`__init__.py` (loc: `/var/www/project/stuff/__init__.py`)

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

`home.py` (loc: `/var/www/project/stuff/home.py`)

```
from stuff import app

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return "This is Home"
```

`run.py` (loc: `/var/www/project/run.py`)

```
from stuff import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug==True)
```

I'm getting a `ModuleNoFoundError: No module named 'stuff'` exception.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my `project.wsgi` (loc: `/var/www/project`)

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/project/stuff/")

from home import app as application
```

and traceback is

```
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.145378 2018] [wsgi:error] File "/var/www/project/project.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.145384 2018] [wsgi:error] from home import app as application
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.145390 2018] [wsgi:error] File "/var/www/project/stuff/home.py", line 1, in <module>
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.145394 2018] [wsgi:error]     from stuff import app
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.145407 2018] [wsgi:error] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stuff'
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.227614 2018] [wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=3172): Target WSGI script '/var/www/project/project.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://52.195.0.108/
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.227668 2018] [wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=3172): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/project/project.wsgi'., referer: http://52.195.0.108/
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.227898 2018] [wsgi:error] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://52.195.0.108/
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.227927 2018] [wsgi:error] File "/var/www/project/project.wsgi", line 6, in <module>, referer: http://52.195.0.108/
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.227933 2018] [wsgi:error]   from home import app as application, referer: http://52.195.0.108/
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.227940 2018] [wsgi:error] File "/var/www/project/stuff/home.py", line 1, in <module>, referer: http://52.195.0.108/
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.227944 2018] [wsgi:error]   from stuff import app, referer: http://52.195.0.108/
[Thu Nov 22 12:54:06.227957 2018] [wsgi:error] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stuff', referer: http://52.195.0.108/
```

Comment: when i seperation app = Flask(__name__) by using __init__.py it gives me no module error

Comment: Sounds like you are not using `run.py` at all then, and are importing `home` somewhere *directly* without a proper package namespace. Please include *how you actually run the flask code* (command line commands, WSGI configuration, or similar) and the full traceback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i added my wsgi and traceback

Comment: Glad we were of help! However, please don't add 'solved' to your post. This is not a bug tracker or ticket system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your package directory on the module search path:

```
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/project/stuff/")
```

*Don't do this*. Python can't find the `stuff` package inside `/var/www/project/stuff/`. You should be importing `stuff.home`, not `home`:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/project")

from stuff.home import app as application
```

That you import `app` from `home` is a bit.. backward. You may want to restructure your project to create the Flask `app` object and the home routes in separate submodules:

`stuff/__init__.py`:

```
from . import app, home

application = app.app
```

`stuff/app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

`stuff/home.py`:

```
from .app import app

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return "This is Home"
```

You can remove `run.py` altogether. Use the `flask` command line app to run your code when developing:

```
FLASK_APP=stuff flask run
```

I used `.` to make the imports relative to the current package, so you can more easily rename `stuff` to something else.

Comment: thanks for ur help but i have another question. why seperating? why not use only __init__.py? how about inserting app.py code to __init__.py and use from stuff import app?

Comment: and where should i use FLASK_APP=stuff flask run ? i load my code using apache2

Comment: @임지웅: you are free to structure your project any way you want, you can put everything in `__init__.py` too. But as your project grows, you'll find it easier to maintain your project if you use separate modules in your package. You may want to grow towards a [application factory model](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/) to handle configuration better, for example.

Comment: @임지웅: `flask run` replaces your `run.py` file, you don't need it if you are only using Apache2. But when you are *developing your project* you may want to use `flask run` to give you automatic reloading and debugging information in the browser. See the [quickstart documentation on *Debug Mode*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#debug-mode).

Answer (score -1):

when i use

home.py (loc: /var/www/project/stuff/home.py)

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return "This is Home"
```

run.py (loc: /var/www/project/run.py)

```
from stuff import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug==True)
```

this works

Comment: This can't work because you still don't import `stuff.home` And if this worked, then *your original code wouldn't throw a `ModuleNotFound` exception either*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters umm.. i tried on my server and it works just by using that code, and original code does throws exception... i tried

Comment: Yes, but we made the assumption that you used `run.py` and that that threw the exception. Without a full traceback in your question and no details on how you are running Flask, we can't really help you beyond that. If you have WSGI configuration that points directly to the `home.py` file, then you are running the wrong setup there and Python has no package context.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i added plz help :(